# C++11 initialization syntax issue (with gcc 4.5 / 4.6)

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, gcc4.6

What is wrong with the following C++11 code:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    float b;
};

struct T
{
    T(S s) {}
};

int main()
{
    T t(S{1, 0.1});  // ERROR HERE
}
```

gcc gives an error at the indicated line (I tried both gcc 4.5 and an experimental build of gcc 4.6)

Is this not valid C++11, or is gcc's implementation incomplete?

EDIT: Here are the compiler errors:

```
test.cpp: In function int main():
test.cpp:14:10: error: expected ) before { token
test.cpp:14:10: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before { token
test.cpp:14:18: error: expected primary-expression before ) token
test.cpp:14:18: error: expected ; before ) token
```

Comment: The latter is definitely the case in general - particularly for GCC4.5.x. GCC4.6.x is more complete, but also buggy.  Update if you possibly can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to proposal [N2640](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf), your code ought to work; a temporary S object should be created. g++ apparently tries to parse this statement as a declaration (of a function t expecting S), so it looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems wrong to call a constructor without parentheses, and this seems to work:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    float b;
};

struct T
{
    T(S s) {}
};

int main()
{
    T t(S({1, 0.1}));  // NO ERROR HERE, due to nice constructor parentheses
    T a({1,0.1}); // note that this works, as per link of Martin.
}
```

It would seem logical (at least to me `:s`) that your example doesn't work. Replacing S with a `vector<int>` gives the same result.

```
vector<int> v{0,1,3}; // works
T t(vector<int>{0,1,2}); // does not, but
T t(vector<int>({0,1,2})); // does
```

Comment: Doesn't that work for the exact same reason that `T a({1,0.1});` works? i.e. isn't `T t(vector<int>({0,1,2}));` just calling the copy constructor of `vector<int>`?

Comment: Well, two things you can do here: either insert somee parentheses or send a mail to the gcc mailing list to discuss this. The main problem I see is that there are many proposals and addenda for this feature, and I don't know which one GCC wants to implement...

Comment: @dvide right. `T a({1, 0.1})` calls the copy/move constructor of `T`, and initializes the (reference-) parameter of that constructor by a temporary as if initialized by `T tmp = {1, 0.1}`. If you say `S({1, 0.1})` instead of `S{1, 0.1}` you just have added one useless copy/move constructor call instead of directly initializing the object's members.